# Matlab Fatal Error on Startup

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab 2014a on windows 8.1 for quite a long time. It was working great until today. Now whenever I open matlab it give me the error shown in the picture.

[image: http://i60.tinypic.com/245zj9u.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the things you might want to check,

1) Firewall settings that are blocking Mathworks software comms.
2) Java version compatiblity - unlikely but may be possible
3) Licence period on specific toolboxes/blocksets.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities which causes this problem

1). one way to solve is by disabling your anti-virus software

2). another is 'There are components of MATLAB that may not work properly under a different version of the JVM(Java virtual machine)', check supported jvm version for Matlab 2014a , there might be a latest version change installed recently.